# Count Number of rows edited in last week

Tags: mysql

I want to count number of rows edited in the last week
for current week i am using this query

```
SELECT COUNT( signup ) AS  `count` FROM  `users` WHERE DATE( signup ) >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7) AND CURDATE()
```

This gives me the answer

> 2294

when i try this to count for the last week .it doesnt count properly

```
SELECT COUNT( signup ) AS  `count` FROM  `users` WHERE DATE( signup ) >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 14) AND SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
```

and this gives me the answer

> 3000

But the correct answer should be

> 3000-2294=704

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `AND CURDATE()`?

Answer (score 1):

In both of your queries below, the second condition is always true because `curdate()` and `SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)` both return non-zero non-null value which MySQL evaluates as true.

```
where date (signup) >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
and CURDATE()
```

is as same as:

```
where date (signup) >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
```

and in the second query:

```
where date (signup) >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 14)
and SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
```

is same as

```
where date (signup) >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 14)
```

#### To fix this:

You probably want to use `between`:

```
select COUNT(signup) as `count`
from `users`
where date (signup) between SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
        and CURDATE()
```

and

```
select COUNT(signup) as `count`
from `users`
where date (signup) between SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 14)
        and SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
```

Comment: @user7550234 - Glad it helped.

Comment: @user7550234 You can optimise this by rewriting it to remove the function on the date column

Answer (score 0):

Both queries are wrong and won't give the correct results. The `WHERE` is

```
WHERE DATE( signup ) >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7) AND CURDATE()
```

but it should be using `BETWEEN`

```
WHERE DATE( signup ) BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7) AND CURDATE()
```

in both queries.

Currently, the `CURDATE()` / `SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)` is true if there's any date in the column

Comment: Thanks .I just tested this and it worked
    SELECT COUNT( signup ) AS  `count` FROM  `users` WHERE DATE( signup ) BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 14) AND SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)